# proving pointwise convergence formally

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble formally proving this simple sequence of functions is pointwise continuous, I know the limit should be $0$.

$f_n(x) = 0$ for $ x < n$ and $f_n(x) = 1/x$ for $ x \geq n$ Could someone show me how to formally prove it?

Comment: I assume you mean "pointwise convergent" and not "pointwise continuous?"

Answer (score 5):

Take any point $x$ under consideration. You have (correctly) guessed that the limit is $f \equiv 0$. Thus, you need to demonstrate, that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $N$ so that

$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |f_n(x)| \leq \epsilon
$$

if $n \geq N$.

In particular, what happens if you choose $N > x$?

(further, you can prove this sequence of functions is *uniformly* continuous, meaning the $N$ doesn't need to depend on $x$: for every $\epsilon > 0$, you can find $N$ so that $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for *all* $x$ and $n \geq N$)

To elaborate: To demonstrate *pointwise* convergence, choose $x$ **first**. Then choose $N$. In particular, if you choose $N > x$, then $n > x$ as well, and you never have to consider $x \geq n$.

If you instead want to demonstrate *uniform* convergence, choose your $\epsilon > 0$, then choose $N$ so that $N > 1/\epsilon$. Now, choose any $x$ and any $n \geq N$. We have to show that $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$.

So, either $x < n$ or $x \geq n$. If $x < n$, then $f_n(x) = 0$ and you are done. Otherwise, $$|f_n(x)| = \dfrac1x \leq \dfrac1n \leq \dfrac1N < \epsilon.$$

What is the difference here?

For pointwise convergence, you can choose $N$ that depends on $x$ and $\epsilon$.

For uniform convergence, you must choose $N$ that *only* depends on $\epsilon$ and not on $x$.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by $N > x$ I get no where with that. If I choose $N$ s.t. $ N< x$ I get that $|f_n(x) |  = |1/x| < 1/N$ but I'm not sure how to include $n$ here and conclude the answer

Comment: If $N > x$ and $n \geq N$, then $x < n$. What is $f_n(x)$ in this case?

Comment: But that's the easy case, I'm curious about the harder $x \geq n$ case

Comment: You don't have to consider that case ($x \geq n$) for proving **pointwise** convergence. I have edited my answer to include more detail.